# Does escape analysis handles Thread.holdsLock() properly?

Tags: java, jvm, escape-analysis

This example works fine (prints true) when I run it with `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -server`:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
synchronized (lock) {
    System.out.println(Thread.holdsLock(lock)); // prints true
}
```

On the other hand, the short and not too detailed [Java HotSpot™ Virtual Machine Performance Enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html) documentation says the following:

> The server compiler also eliminates locks for all non-globally escaping objects.

So, if escape analysis eliminates the unnecessary synchronization here it should print `false`.

I guess escape analysis handles `holdsLock` properly (eliminates locks does not broke `holdsLock()`) but I would like to see some official reference or maybe relevant JVM source code snippets.

Comment: This code should *never* print `false`. Optimizations are only allowed, if they don’t change the semantic of the code. If a JVM decides to eliminate the lock, it’s also responsible to replace the `Thread.holdsLock(lock)` by the constant `true` at this point. There is no source code cite necessary to back up the fundamental property that optimizations are not allowed to change the semantic. Besides that, there’s more than one implementation so citing the source code of one of them wouldn’t be a proof anyway. A JVM could also decide not to optimize when you call `Thread.holdsLock(lock)`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.holdsLock` is a [native](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1591) method in JDK, and it is not a [JVM intrinsic](https://gist.github.com/apangin/8bc69f06879a86163e490a61931b37e8).

This means, the implementation of `Thread.holdsLock` is a black box for JIT compiler. Since this method accepts `lock` as an argument, `lock` can no longer be considered as a local non-escapable object. JVM knows for sure, that `lock` **does escape**, so neither allocation nor synchronization may be eliminated in this example.

But, as @Holger noticed, even if `holdsLock` was a JVM intrinsic, it should never return `false`, otherwise this would be a specification violation. No JVM optimization may break the correctness of a program.

Comment: As a general rule, 99.9% of calls to libraries have no special optimisation or understanding for the JVM. There is a very short list of very specific cases where this happens based on where the JVM designer consider it to be very common and a quick win to avoid complexity. +1